# handle management with boost::shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I would like to use boost::shared_ptr<> to encapsulate the lifetime management of a handle. My handle and it's creation/destruction functions are declared like this:

```
typedef const struct MYHANDLE__ FAR* MYHANDLE;

void CloseMyHandle( MYHANDLE );
MYHANDLE CreateMyHandle();
```

Ideally, I would like to use the `boost::shared_ptr<>` like this to manage the handle:

```
boost::shared_ptr< void > my_handle( CreateMyHandle(), &CloseMyHandle );
```

Unfortunately, because the handle is declared as a `const struct *` instead of the usual `void *`, I get errors like this:

```
boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(199) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const MYHANDLE__ *' to 'void *'
```

I can use a functor to cast the `void *` to a `MYHANDLE` like this:

```
struct DeallocateMyHandle
{ 
    void operator()( void* handle )
    {
        CloseMyHandle( ( MYHANDLE )handle ); 
    };
};

boost::shared_ptr< void > my_handle( ( void* )CreateMyHandle(), DeallocateMyHandle() );
```

But, I'd rather have a method that doesn't involve the separate functor. Is there a way to do this just within the `boost::shared_ptr<>` constructor that I'm not seeing? Or, am I stuck with the functor?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Why are you using a `shared_ptr<void>` instead of a `shared_ptr<MYHANDLE>`?

Comment: @James McNellis - using `shared_ptr<MYHANDLE>` yields this error: `boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(199) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const MYHANDLE__*' to 'MYHANDLE *'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `shared_ptr` type needs to be this:

```
boost::shared_ptr< const MYHANDLE__ FAR>
```

That way when `shared_ptr` makes a pointer out of it, it becomes:

```
const MYHANDLE__ FAR*
```

Which matches your `MYHANDLE` type exactly:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct MYHANDLE__ {};
typedef const MYHANDLE__* MYHANDLE;

void CloseMyHandle(MYHANDLE) {}
MYHANDLE CreateMyHandle(void) { return 0; }

int main()
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<const MYHANDLE__> ptr_type;
    ptr_type my_handle( CreateMyHandle(), &CloseMyHandle );
}
```

---

Note, I *really* doubt you need `FAR`, that's from the 16-bit ages. It expands to either `far` or nothing, depending on if you're compiling for 16-bit (hint: you aren't compiling to 16-bit. :) ). `far` isn't even an extension anymore, as far as I know.

Also, like Martin said don't use double-underscores anywhere.

Comment: Ah! Of course! Thanks! 
As a side note, the handle definition is not mine and I cannot change it. I believe its predecessors may harken back to the 16-bit days. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use:

```
boost::shared_ptr< const MYHANDLE__ > my_handle( CreateMyHandle(), &CloseMyHandle );
```

PS. Note the use of double underscore is not allowed (it is reserved for the implementation).
See: [Rules about identifers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#22797)

Comment: What makes you think that MYHANDLE__ isn't an implementation name?

Comment: Because it starts with MY ( as in mine rather than my initials)

Comment: Still looks like a double underscore to me.  Any name with double underscores (or leading underscore followed by a capital letter) is reserved for the implementation.

Comment: using `MYHANDLE__` yields this error: `boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(199) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const MYHANDLE__ *' to 'MYHANDLE__ *'`

Comment: @PaulH: What happens if you add const to the type in shared pointer? (as edited above). PS it is not usual to hide const inside the typedef. Normally the typedef only contains the struct part (and that is really only in C (not in C++). Then you use const explicitly around the code so it is obvious (sometimes const goes in the name but you should reflect that in the name of the typedef to make it obvious).

Answer (score 2):

If HANDLE is a public type, but the type it points to is not, there's a really easy way to write this:

```
template <typename T> struct unpointer { };
template <typename T> struct unpointer<T*> { typedef T type; };
boost::shared_ptr<typename unpointer<MYHANDLE>::type> my_handle(
  CreateMyHandle(), &CloseMyHandle);
```

(If you're using a really old version of VC++ or gcc you probably have to omit the "typename" there.)

Of course this gets a bit verbose and tedious. If you're only got one handle type to deal with, you probably to write this:

```
typedef typename unpointer<MYHANDLE>::type MYHANDLEREF;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MYHANDLEREF> my_shared_ptr;
```

If you've got all kinds of handles to wrap (and since it looks like you're doing Win32 API stuff, you probably do), create a template that wraps things up at whatever level you prefer (a class template that just generates the types, a `handle_ptr<T>` that subclasses `shared_ptr<unpointer<T>>` and adds the default deleted for you, a `handle_ref<T>` that uses a `shared_ptr` behind the scenes to fake being a `MYHANDLE &` instead of faking being what `MYHANDLE` is a pointer to, etc.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and C++11 template aliases make it even simpler. You can define `template<typename T> using shared_handle = std::shared_ptr<typename unpointer<T>::type>;` and then use it as `shared_handle<MYHANDLE>`.